# 'go to symbol' in Allround Automation PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: plsql-developer

I really like using my PC just by keyboard and any time I have to use a mouse is a real pain for me. I really like 'go to symbol' feature in VS Code or Sublime Text, so I can navigate through any source code with ease. Is there anything that would bring this feature also into PL/SQL Developer, so I would be able to easily navigate through my PL/SQL packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin [rrProject](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/plug-ins) adds some keyboard features. The Code Contents List Tool allows you to find the function or procedure of the code contents panel and go to it. The IDE Insight tool is a global search for windows, connections, menu items and browser objects and performing the necessary action.

It’s not exactly that 'go to symbol', but it allows you to use the mouse less.